# HTTP POST to GET - XML into php-data types

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, http-get

I'm currently writing a simple iOS application that creates an .XML file and sends the data to an address URL (xx.xx.xx.xx/par.php) via a HTTP-POST method.
I'm at the stage where i begin writing the parse script to recieve the .XML file and insert that data into simple memory locations.

I have virtually no experience with php or server-side coding. I've rented out a few books from my library, but would like to find some code to work with.

Comment: Check out [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Instead of using a custom XML representation this might be a case where you should use XML-RPC, which has exact mappings to PHP data types.